# How can I use a button in Tkinter to stop a different line of code from running?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a personal project to attempt to get better at python. The game I am making is Yahtzee. I have it setup to where you can roll all of the die and it will tell you what you have. I also have a window setup using Tkinter. What I am trying to do is have a button that says "HOLD" underneath each number. If you know how yahtzee works you would know why. I just want this button to stop that dice from rolling again after your first roll.

I have looked at other posts here on Stack Overflow, but none of the posts are in the way I have been trying to figure out.

```
# Window
def hold():


window = Tk()
window.title("Sam's Yahtzee")
window.configure(background="black")
Button(window, text="HOLD", width=6, command=hold) .grid(row=3, column=0, 
sticky=W)
window.mainloop()

# Dice Roll
roll1 = random.randint(1, 6)
roll2 = random.randint(1, 6)
roll3 = random.randint(1, 6)
roll4 = random.randint(1, 6)
roll5 = random.randint(1, 6)
print(roll1, roll2, roll3, roll4, roll5)

# Choosing What Num to Hold


# Roll Num Storing
userRollHold = {'roll1': roll1,
            'roll2': roll2,
            'roll3': roll3,
            'roll4': roll4,
            'roll5': roll5}
```

I am hoping for a button that will be able to stop a number from being rolled again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Checkbutton` for the hold buttons and check their states to determine whether the corresponding dice is to be held on next roll.  Below is an sample code (use `Checkbutton` as the dice itself):

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

root = Tk()
root.title("Sam's Yahtzee")

def roll(dice, times):
    if times > 0:
        dice['text'] = randint(1, 6)
        root.after(10, roll, dice, times-1)

def roll_dices():
    for i in range(5):
        if dices[i][1].get() == 0:
            # dice is not held, so roll it
            roll(dices[i][0], 10)

dices = []
for i in range(5):
    ivar = IntVar()
    dice = Checkbutton(root, text=randint(1, 6), variable=ivar, bg='silver', bd=1, font=('Arial', 24), indicatoron=False, height=3, width=5)
    dice.grid(row=0, column=i)
    dices.append([dice, ivar])

Button(text='Dice', command=roll_dices, height=2, font=(None, 16, 'bold')).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky='ew')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I want to thank you so much for this! This helped soooo much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could create a class with a hold attribute and set and unset that as per your requirements:

For Example:

```
class Dice:
    def __init__(self):
        self.held = False
        self.val = None

    def roll(self):
        self.val = random.randint(1, 6) if not self.held else self.val
        return self.val

    def hold(self):
        self.held = True

    def unhold(self):
        self.held = False
```

Here is a proof-of-concept test code:

```
dice_1, dice_2, dice_3 = Dice(), Dice(), Dice()
print dice_1.roll(), dice_2.roll(), dice_3.roll()
dice_1.hold()
dice_3.hold()
print dice_1.roll(), dice_2.roll(), dice_3.roll()
print dice_1.roll(), dice_2.roll(), dice_3.roll()
dice_1.unhold()
print dice_1.roll(), dice_2.roll(), dice_3.roll()
```

Output:

```
5 3 5
5 1 5
5 6 5
3 1 5
```